# Expected earliest point at which a sock matches an earlier sock

Tags: probability, combinatorics, asymptotics, approximation, expected-value

The University of Waterloo CEMC's [Problem of the Month](https://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/resources/potm.php) for November, the problem statement for which can be seen [here](https://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/resources/potm/2020-21/POTM-20-2-NOV-P.pdf), was authored by me. (As far as I know, it is original, though I have come to expect that such low hanging fruits have already been plucked. Forgive me if someone authored a similar problem earlier.)

In essence, I was inspired by the fact that I had $n$ pairs of matching socks in a laundry bag and I was pulling socks out one at a time and hoping that, at some point, I would obtain a sock that matched a previously drawn sock (this was before I had degenerated to the point that I did not care about my socks matching). The main part of the problem asks for the pulled sock number $k+1$ at which **the probability is highest** that the earliest match occurs. The official solution can be read [here](https://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/resources/potm/2020-21/POTM-20-2-NOV-S.pdf) and it interestingly has to do with triangular numbers.

Given $2n$ total socks (so $n$ pairs of matching socks), the probability of the first match occurring upon removing the $(k+1)^{\text{th}}$ sock for $1\le k\le n$ is $$P(n,k) = \frac{k2^k n! (2n-k-1)!}{(2n)!(n-k)!}.$$ For those wondering, this probability is the same regardless of whether the socks within a single pair are distinguishable or indistinguishable, though in reality, they are of course indistinguishable.

This means the **expected sock number** at which the first match occurs is $$E(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k\cdot P(n,k)} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{k^2 2^k n! (2n-k-1)!}{(2n)!(n-k)!}}.$$
According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=compute%20%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7Bk%5E2%202%5Ek%20n%21%20%282n-k-1%29%21%7D%7B%282n%29%21%28n-k%29%21%7D%7D%20for%20n%3D9), the first $9$ values of this function are: $$1,\frac{5}{3},\frac{11}{5},\frac{93}{35},\frac{193}{63},\frac{793}{231},\frac{1619}{429},\frac{26333}{6435},\frac{53381}{12155}.$$
Does it seem to grow like a square root? I'm not sure.

**My question is:** Can this expected value function be written in a closed form, or be approximated by bounds or by an asymptotic formula?

Comment: It ought to grow like a square root by the birthday paradox.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I would be interested in more details, such as the version of the birthday paradox to which you are referring and if there are any coefficients in this case.

Comment: It is just intuition. This is not exactly any version of the birthday paradox, because there are only two socks of each kind; however, very roughly, by the time the first match happens, this won't have a significant effect. For the actual value, we need to do the math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your "expected sock number" is $1$ off, because $P(n,k)$ is the probability for the $(k+1)^{\text{th}}$ sock. I am making this correction because the formula when you add $1$ is nicer. So I will give a formula for the sequence $$2, \frac83, \frac{16}{5}, \frac{128}{35}, \dots$$ which is shifted by $1$ from your sequence. (Just *looking* at this might lead you to some guesses about what the formula is!)

It is often easier to compute the expected value of a
(nonnegative integer-valued) random variable $\mathbf X$ by the formula
$$
   \mathbb E[\mathbf X] = \sum_{k \ge 0} \Pr[\mathbf X > k].
$$
(You can check that $\Pr[\mathbf X = k]$ is counted exactly $k$ times in this sum.) In this case, $\Pr[\mathbf X > k]$ is the probability that the first $k$ socks are all different. This has a nicer formula: $$\Pr[\mathbf X > k] = \frac{\binom{n}{k} 2^k}{\binom{2n}{k}} = \frac{n!(2n-k)!2^k}{(2n)!(n-k)!} = \frac{\binom{2n-k}{k}2^k}{\binom{2n}{n}}.$$ So we now want to evaluate the sum
$$
   \mathbb E[\mathbf X] = \frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n-k}{n}2^{k}.
$$
This sum has a combinatorial interpretation: $\binom{2n-k}{n}2^{k}$ is [A276418](https://oeis.org/A276418), the number of paths of length $2n$ that start at $0$, go up or down at each step, and return to $0$ exactly $k$ times. (I don't know if there's an easy argument that counts these.) Summing these over all $k$ gives $4^n$: the number of paths of length $2n$ that start at $0$ and go up or down at each step.

Therefore $\mathbb E[\mathbf X] = 4^n/\binom{2n}{n}$. Asymptotically as $n \to \infty$, $\mathbb E[\mathbf X] \sim \sqrt{\pi n}$.

Comment: Amazing! I was not at all expecting a closed formula to exist.